# Possible use of Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity?

Tags: functions, problem-solving

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(ax+by) +f(ay-bx) = (f(a) +f(b)) (f(x) +f(y)) $

for all values of a, x, b, y.

I was able to show that $f(x) = 1/2$ and $f(x) =x^2$ are solutions but I can't show if they are the only ones. 
I had the feeling that Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity would be used here looking at it but I wasn't able to use it.

Comment: Please show how you got $\frac 12, x^2 $ to generalize.

Comment: I got f(a^2) =(f(a))^2 from which I was able to guess f(x) =x^2

Comment: what is Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity? never heard of it. please provide a reference. (eg. wiki links).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity

Comment: What is the source of this question?